# ng-repeat not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, web-sql

I have an `ng-repeat` that looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat = "Header in Headers" ng-show = "Headers.length > 0">
            <div class = "promoHeader">
                {{Header.Descript1}}
            </div>
            <div class="touchcarousel minimal-light promosCarousel">
                <ul class="touchcarousel-container">
                    <li ng-repeat = "Promo in Header.Promos" class="touchcarousel-item" ng-class = "{'disabledPromo' : invalidPromo(Promo)}">
                        <a id = "{{Promo.PromoID}}" ng-click = "viewPromo(Promo)">
                            <img class = "tcimage" ng-src = "{{Promo.PhotoURL}}"/>
                            <div class = "tctext"><span class = "tctext-inner">{{Promo.Descript1}}</span></div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For some reason `Header.Descript1` is taking the value of `Promo.Descript1`. What makes no sense is that it works fine in `Android` but breaks in `iOS`. This is a `cordova 3.3.0` application with `jQuery Mobile` and `angularjs`. I took a look at the `DOM` in `weinre` but that hasn't helped. Perhaps there is a compatibility issue between `iOS` and `angularjs`?

**Edit**

It appears the issue is caused in `WebSQL` not `angular`:

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM PromoHead INNER JOIN Promo ON PromoHead.HeadID = Promo.HeadID ORDER BY PromoHead.SortOrder', [], function (tx, results){
                    for (var i = 0; i<results.rows.length; i++)
                    {
                            headers.push({
                                HeadID : results.rows.item(i).HeadID,
                                Descript1 : results.rows.item(i).Descript1, 
                                Promos : []
                            });
                    }
                }, errorCB); 
            }, errorCB);
```

I checked `PromoHead` and it has the correct values. When I perform this `inner join`, however, `PromoHead` takes the value of the first `Promo` row in the results. This error only occurs on `iOS`, `android` works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by explicitly stating the columns I need from `PromoHead`

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT PromoHead.HeadID, PromoHead.Descript1, PromoHead.SortOrder FROM PromoHead INNER JOIN Promo ON PromoHead.HeadID = Promo.HeadID ORDER BY PromoHead.SortOrder'...
```

Answer (score 1):

The spaces around the attribute definitions could be causing an issue